# SCIP Optimization of an Exponential Function

Tags: python, optimization, exponential, scip, objective-function

I am having issues summing over an exponential equation and using
this as is the objective function.

I have also tried writing the exponential equation in as
a constraint as I thought that may be another method to solve this
issue, but this did not work for me as well.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyscipopt import Model, quicksum, multidict, exp

num_fac_to_open = 1
order_to_open = []
opened_fac = []
closed_fac = [0, 1, 2]
S = [0, 1, 2]
R = [10, 11, 12]
distance_dict = {(0, 10): 300.8, (1, 10): 150.6, (2, 10): 1567.8, (0, 11): 1241.0, (1, 11): 2012.1, (2, 11): 789.2, (0, 12): 563.2, (1, 12): 1798.3, (2, 12): 946.3}
population_dict = {10:54, 11:46, 12:22}

# n is the desired number of facilities to open
n = len(opened_fac) + num_fac_to_open
# create a model
model = Model()

z, y= {}, {}
for s in S:
    # x_i is binary, 1 if service facility i is opened, 0 otherwise
    z[s] = model.addVar(vtype="B")
    for r in R:
        # y_i,j is binary, 1 if service facility i is assigned to residential area j, 0 otherwise
        y[s, r] = model.addVar(vtype="B")

for r in R:
    want_list = (distance_dict[s, r]*y[s, r] for s in S)
    want_list_quicksum = quicksum(want_list)
    exp_power = population_dict[r]*want_list_quicksum
    w = exp(exp_power)

model.setObjective(quicksum([w]), 'minimize')
model.optimize()
```

The error that occurs from this code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack_overflow_code.py", line 38, in <module>
    model.setObjective(quicksum([w]), 'minimize')
  File "src/pyscipopt/scip.pyx", line 1246, in pyscipopt.scip.Model.setObjective
AssertionError: given coefficients are neither Expr or number but SumExpr
```

It is my understanding that the format of the objective function should be (which is the result I get from printing exp_power):

```
Expr({Term(): 0.0, Term(x4): 12390.400000000001, Term(x8): 39562.6, Term(x12): 20818.6})
```

However, once the exponential term is added (w), the format becomes:

```
exp(sum(0.0,prod(12390.400000000001,x4),prod(39562.6,x8),prod(20818.6,x12)))
```

Further, when adding the quicksum[w], the format becomes:

```
sum(0.0,exp(sum(0.0,prod(12390.400000000001,x4),prod(39562.6,x8),prod(20818.6,x12))))
```

The aim is to minimize \sum_{r=1}^N W_r

Where \W_r = exp(population_dict[r]*sum_{s∈S} d_r,s * y_r,s)  ∀r ∈ R

Answer (score 0):

`quicksum` takes an iterable, but `distance_dict[s, r]*y[s, r] for s in S` is not returning an iterable as you are probably expecting.

Try simplifying that line into multiple lines and making sure you have a list to work with before feeding it into `quicksum`.

In order to use list comprehension in Python we must wrap our statement in square brackets. `[distance_dict[s, r]*y[s, r] for s in S]`.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for the help. I changed that section of the code which fixes the error I was having with that issue. However, I still think there is an issue with the exponential and quicksum in the objective function. It is my understanding that the error comes from it not being in the correct format. If you have any more suggestions and able to provide help that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have also updated the problem and shown the different formats that I am getting

Comment: Please post a new question for this, it's now a different issue and you've changed the original question. I've submitted a request to revert back to the original question

Comment: Hi Matt, here is the link to the new question, cheers :)                                                  
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65695286/scip-objective-function-quicksum-over-a-exponential-term)